# In R, how do I get confidence interval of group means obtained from lda()

Tags: r, lda, confidence-interval

I have a data.table MEG with a continuous independent variable (called "metric") and a categorical dependent variable (called "team") and I want a model to predict "team" given "metric", i.e., I want the mean and the corresponding confidence interval for each group. I used lda() function in the package MASS. I got the group means but I am unable to figure out how to get the CI. I tried using confint() but the output from lda(team ~ metric, data = MEG) is of class lda and confint() does not take objects of class lda. My data looks like below but with 2500 rows:

```
team    metric
A       34105
A       37135
A       38574
B       13597
B       12952
C       75123
C       59452
C       62993
C       57679
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: My question is a subset of someone else's question asked here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-June/134499.html but no one answered her question.

Comment: If you have a formula, we can work something out. Otherwise it's a statistical question and should be moved to crossvalidated.com. Which is it?